# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Clicked' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Hii all, its my first question here  i got this TypeError but didnt
>   understend why ... please assist.
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Clicked' of undefined

```
class TableComp extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        id:"",
        name:"",
        percentage:"",
        status:""
    }

}
Clicked(data){
  this.setState({
      id:data.id,
      name:data.name,
      percentage:data.percentage,
      status:data.status
  });
}

PrintTable(){
  return (Data.tasks.map(function(data,key){
      return(
      <tr key={key} onClick={() => this.Clicked(data)}> 
      <td>{data.id}</td>
      <td>{data.name}</td>
      <td>{data.percentage}</td>
      <td>{data.status}</td>
      </tr>
  )})); 
}

render(){
    return(
        <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
        <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Percentage</th>
         <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {this.PrintTable()}
        </tbody>
        </Table>
    )


}

}
```

i try to use the normal way with .bind but same issue ...

Comment: I think it's the context of `this`, it is changed from arrow function, surround `this.Clicked(data)` with `{}` normally it's gonna works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You were right that you should bind your functions in the constructor as you already mentioned.
2. The problem is your usage of `this` inside a function in another function. In that case `this` does not refer to the class. To fix this pass an arrow function to your map(). By that your avoiding this issue.

You can read more about this [here](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html#sec_traditional-functions-bad-non-methods)

Answer (score 0):

you should bind your functions to the component, change your ctor to be like this:

```
constructor(props){
super(props)

this.PrintTable = this.PrintTable.bind(this);
this.Clicked = this.Clicked.bind(this);

this.state={
    id:"",
    name:"",
    percentage:"",
    status:""
}

}
```

[here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) is full explanation what and why you should bind your functions:

Comment: What does ctor mean?

Comment: ctor is constructor

Answer (score 0):

```
Clicked(data){
  this.setState({
      id:data.id,
      name:data.name,
      percentage:data.percentage,
      status:data.status
  });
}
```

should be:

```
clicked = (data) => {
  this.setState({
      id:data.id,
      name:data.name,
      percentage:data.percentage,
      status:data.status
  });
}
```

i.e. you need to bind your functions to call them like `this.function()`. Note that it's also best practice to use function names like `functionName()`, and not `FunctionName()`.